# Url rewrite first path segment to subdomain

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do the below with a rewrite. From my attempts so far, it doesn't appear possible since I don't think I have access to rewrite the host.

`domain.com/sub/web/mypage` needs to become `sub.domain.com/web/mypage`

Essentially trying to do the opposite of this: [URL Rewrite city.domain.com to domain.com/city](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-rewrite-city-domain-com-to-domain-com-city)

Was hoping to figure out a rewrite or something so I don't have to spend weeks fixing routes in a legacy webforms application that's very coupled to the expected subdomain url pattern.

My thought was to rewrite on a proxy server and send to the server farm with the "old" subdomain url and it would maybe "just work".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to redirect from `https://doman.com/sub/web/mypage` to `https://sub.domain.com/web/mypage`? if so, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />               
           <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/sub/web/mypage" />
      </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="https://sub.domain.com/web/mypage" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: While this didn't solve the problem. It put me on the right track of what to do. I discovered I can replace IIS Server variables and just replaced the HTTP_Host variable with what I needed and it worked as expected. Thanks.